# Task list with re-ordering feature using Firebase/Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a list of tasks that can change their order, but I am not sure how to store this in a database.

I don't want to use array because I have to do some queries further in future.

Here is the screenshot of my database:

[image: Database screenshot]

I'm trying to make something like Trello where the user adds tasks and can move tasks upward and downward according to their priority. I need to change the position of the tasks in the database as well to maintain the record. I'm unable to understand how to do that in any database. I'm an experienced developer and I have worked with mongodb and firebase but this is something unique for me.

Here is the code to create and get all tasks. When I try to move some task in collection. I maintained an index in each task.
Let's say when I move a task from the position of index 5 to index 2 then I have to edit all the upcoming indexes by +1. Is there some way I can avoid doing this?

### Code Sample

```swift
class taskManager {
    static let shared = taskManager()
    typealias TasksCompletion = (_ tasks:[Task],_ error:String?)->Void
    typealias SucessCompletion = (_ error:String?)->Void

    func addTask(task:Task,completion:@escaping SucessCompletion){
        Firestore.firestore().collection("tasks").addDocument(data: task.toDic) { (err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

    func getAllTask(completion:@escaping TasksCompletion){
        Firestore.firestore().collection("tasks")
            .addSnapshotListener { taskSnap, error in
                taskSnap?.documentChanges.forEach({ (task) in
                    let object = task.document.data()
                    let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: .prettyPrinted)
                    var taskData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Task.self, from: json)
                    taskData.id = task.document.documentID

                    if (task.type == .added) {
                        Task.shared.append(taskData)
                    }
                    if (task.type == .modified) {
                        let index = Task.shared.firstIndex(where: { $0.id ==  taskData.id})!
                        Task.shared[index] = taskData
                    }
                })
                if error == nil{
                    completion(Task.shared,nil)
                }else{
                    completion([],error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Provide a more detailed problem description along with code you have tried that isn't working

Comment: The correct solution is going to be related to the size of your data set, does the user want different ‘views’ of the data (like playlists in iTunes) and will the dataset be accessible by multiple users. Is this 100 tasks or millions and is it per user?

Answer (score 16):

I think the question you're trying to ask about is more about **database design**.

When you want to be able to keep order with a group of items while being able to reorder them you will need a column to keep the order.

You run into an issue when you try to order them if they are sequentially ordered.

### Example

For example if you wanted to move `Item1` behind `Item4`:

#### Before

An item with an ordering index.

```
 1. Item1, order: 1
 2. Item2, order: 2
 3. Item3, order: 3
 4. Item4, order: 4
 5. Item5, order: 5
 6. Item6, order: 6
```

#### After

**Problem**: we had to update every record between the item being moved and where it was placed.

**Why this is a problem**: this is a Big O(n) - for every space we move we have to update that many records. As you get more tasks this becomes more of an issue as it will take longer and not scale well. It would be nice to have a Big O(1) where we have a constant amount of changes or as few as possible.

```
 1. Item2, order: 1 - Updated
 2. Item3, order: 2 - Updated
 3. Item4, order: 3 - Updated
 4. Item1, order: 4 - Updated
 5. Item5, order: 5
 6. Item6, order: 6
```

### Possible Solution #1 (OK Maybe?) - Spacing

You could try to come up with a crafty method where you try to space the order numbers out so that you have holes that can be filled without updating multiple records.

This could get tricky though, and you may think, "Why not store Item1 at order: 4.5" I added a [related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195308/storing-a-re-orderable-list-in-a-database) below that goes into that idea and why you should avoid it.

You may be able to verify the safety of the order client side and avoid hitting the database to determine the new order ID of the move.

This also has limitations as you may have to rebalance the spacing or maybe you run out of numbers to items. You may have to check for a conflict and when a conflict arises you perform a rebalance on everything or recursively the items around the conflict making sure that other balancing updates don't cause more conflicts and that additional conflicts are resolved.

```
 1. Item2, order: 200
 2. Item3, order: 300
 3. Item4, order: 400
 4. Item1, order: 450 - Updated
 5. Item5, order: 500
 6. Item6, order: 600
```

### Possible Solution #2 (Better) - Linked Lists

As mentioned in the [related link below](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195308/storing-a-re-orderable-list-in-a-database) you could use a data structure like a linked list. This retains a constant amount of changes to update so it is Big O(1). I will go into a linked list a bit in case you haven't played with the data structure yet.

As you can see below this change only required 3 updates, I believe the max would be 5 as shown in `Expected Updates`. You may be thinking, "Well it took about that many with the first original problem/example!" The thing is that this will always be a max of 5 updates compared to the possibility of thousands or millions with the original approach [Big O(n)].

```
 1. Item2, previous: null, next: Item3 - Updated // previous is now null
 2. Item3, previous: Item2, next: Item4
 3. Item4, previous: Item3, next: Item1 - Updated // next is now Item1
 4. Item1, previous: Item4, next: Item5 - Updated // previous & next updated
 5. Item5, previous: Item1, next: Item4 - Updated // previous is now Item1
 6. Item6, previous: Item6, next: null
```

#### Expected Updates

1. Item being moved (previous, next)
2. Old previous item's next
3. Old next item's previous
4. New previous item's next
5. New next item's previous

#### Linked Lists

I guess I used a `double linked list`. You probably could get away with just using a single linked list where it doesn't have a `previous` attribute and only a `next` instead.

The idea behind a linked list is to think of it a chain link, when you want to move one item you would decouple it from the link in front of it and behind it, then link those links together. Next you would open up where you would want to place it between, now it would have the new links on each side of it, and for those new links they would now be linked to the new link instead of each other.

### Possible Solution #3 - Document/Json/Array Storage

You said you want to stay away from arrays, but you could utilize document storage. You could still have a searchable table of items, and then each collection of items would just have an array of item id/references.

Items Table

```
 - Item1, id: 1
 - Item2, id: 2
 - Item3, id: 3
 - Item4, id: 4
 - Item5, id: 5
 - Item6, id: 6
```

Item Collection

```
 [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6]
```

### Related Question(s)

- [Storing a reorderable list in a database](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195308/storing-a-re-orderable-list-in-a-database)

### Resources on Big O

- [A guide on Big O](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/)
- [More on Big O](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/all-you-need-to-know-about-big-o-notation-to-crack-your-next-coding-interview-9d575e7eec4)
- [Wiki Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

### Other Considerations

Your database design will depend on what you're trying to accomplish. Can items belong to multiple boards or users?

Can you offload some ordering to the client side and allow it to tell the server what the new order is? You should still avoid inefficient ordering algorithms on the client side, but you can get them to do some of the dirty work if you trust them and don't have any issues with data integrity if multiple people are working on the same items at the same time (those are other design problems, that may or may not be related to the DB, depending on how you handle them.)

Comment: For now i assume just todo list so i can re-arrange items

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think linked list is good approach but not do able in firebase and 3rd approach is maintaining a list of ids array so we need to get each id then item againt that id

Comment: The next/previous would just be item id's. I haven't used firebase in a long time but I imagine you can do standard associations. I think in the related questions I linked they even mentioned using a join table to do such. You would need to do a join into the items where the id was in the item collection list for #3 (yet again I don't have much firebase experience, but that'd be the idea with a database). I think your concern is a request per ID with #3, but you should be able to get all of them in one request.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer. I would like to comment on your solutions:

Solution 2 can work great if you have just one list. If a task can appear in more than one list it can get messy fast. You would have to create links for every list you want to use.

Solution 3 is probably the best solution if you want to have several lists. It is easy to maintain and should be performant.

Comment: Solution 1 is the hardest to maintain. But is needed if you want to have a unique ranking of all your tasks over several lists. Atlassian uses this solution for Jira-Boards. Where all issues are ordered no matter in which list they appear. Interestingly they use lexical ordering which reduces the pain of rebasing a bit.

They made an interesting video about it.https://youtu.be/OjQv9xMoFbg

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck on the same problem for a long time. The best solution I found was to order them *Lexicographically*.

Trying to manage a decimal rank (1, 2, 3, 4...) runs into a lot of problems that are all mentioned in other answers on this question. Instead, I store the rank as a string of characters ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'...) and I use the character codes of the characters in the strings to find a spot between to ranks when adjustments are made.

For example, I have:

```
{
    item: "Star Wars",
    rank: "bbb"
},
{
    item: "Lord of the Rings",
    rank: "ccc"
},
{
    item: "Harry Potter",
    rank: "ddd"
},
{
    item: "Star Trek",
    rank: "eee"
},
{
    item: "Game of Thrones",
    rank: "fff"
}
```

Now I want to move `"Game of Thrones"` to the third slot, below `"Lord of the Rings"` (`'ccc'`) and above `"Harry Potter"` (`'ddd'`).

So I use the character codes of `'ccc'` and `'ddd'` to mathematically find the average between the two strings; in this case, that ends up being `'cpp'` and I'll update the document to:

```
{
    item: "Game of Thrones",
    rank: "cpp"
}
```

Now I have:

```
{
    item: "Star Wars",
    rank: "bbb"
},
{
    item: "Lord of the Rings",
    rank: "ccc"
},
{
    item: "Game of Thrones",
    rank: "cpp"
},
{
    item: "Harry Potter",
    rank: "ddd"
},
{
    item: "Star Trek",
    rank: "eee"
}
```

If I run out of room between two ranks, I can simply add a letter to the end of the string; so, between `'bbb'` and `'bbc'`, I can insert `'bbbn'`.

This is a benefit over decimal ranking.

#### Things to be aware of

Do not assign `'aaa'` or `'zzz'` to any item. These need to be withheld to easily allow for moving items to the top or bottom of the list. If `"Star Wars"` has rank `'aaa'` and I want to move something above it, there would be problems. Solvable problems, but this is easily avoided if you start at rank `'bbb'`. Then, if you want to move something above the top rank, you can simply find the average between `'bbb'` and `'aaa'`.

If your list gets reshuffled frequently, it would be good practice to periodically refresh the rankings. If things are moved to the same spot in a list thousands of times, you may get a long string like `'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbn'`. You may want to refresh the list when a string gets to be a certain length.

#### Implementation

The algorithm and an explanation of the functions used to achieve this effect can be found [here](https://medium.com/whisperarts/lexorank-what-are-they-and-how-to-use-them-for-efficient-list-sorting-a48fc4e7849f). Credit for this idea goes to the author of that article.

#### The code I use in my project

Again, credit for this code goes to the author of the article I linked above, but this is the code I have running in my project to find the average between two strings. This is written in Dart for a Flutter app

```
import 'dart:math';

const ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;

String getRankBetween({String firstRank, String secondRank}) {
  assert(firstRank.compareTo(secondRank) < 0,
      "First position must be lower than second. Got firstRank $firstRank and second rank $secondRank");

  /// Make positions equal
  while (firstRank.length != secondRank.length) {
    if (firstRank.length > secondRank.length)
      secondRank += "a";
    else
      firstRank += "a";
  }
  var firstPositionCodes = [];
  firstPositionCodes.addAll(firstRank.codeUnits);
  var secondPositionCodes = [];
  secondPositionCodes.addAll(secondRank.codeUnits);
  var difference = 0;
  for (int index = firstPositionCodes.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    /// Codes of the elements of positions
    var firstCode = firstPositionCodes[index];
    var secondCode = secondPositionCodes[index];

    /// i.e. ' a < b '
    if (secondCode < firstCode) {
      /// ALPHABET_SIZE = 26 for now
      secondCode += ALPHABET_SIZE;
      secondPositionCodes[index - 1] -= 1;
    }

    /// formula: x = a * size^0 + b * size^1 + c * size^2
    final powRes = pow(ALPHABET_SIZE, firstRank.length - index - 1);
    difference += (secondCode - firstCode) * powRes;
  }
  var newElement = "";
  if (difference <= 1) {
    /// add middle char from alphabet
    newElement = firstRank +
        String.fromCharCode('a'.codeUnits.first + ALPHABET_SIZE ~/ 2);
  } else {
    difference ~/= 2;
    var offset = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < firstRank.length; index++) {
      /// formula: x = difference / (size^place - 1) % size;
      /// i.e. difference = 110, size = 10, we want place 2 (middle),
      /// then x = 100 / 10^(2 - 1) % 10 = 100 / 10 % 10 = 11 % 10 = 1
      final diffInSymbols =
          difference ~/ pow(ALPHABET_SIZE, index) % (ALPHABET_SIZE);
      var newElementCode = firstRank.codeUnitAt(secondRank.length - index - 1) +
          diffInSymbols +
          offset;
      offset = 0;

      /// if newElement is greater then 'z'
      if (newElementCode > 'z'.codeUnits.first) {
        offset++;
        newElementCode -= ALPHABET_SIZE;
      }

      newElement += String.fromCharCode(newElementCode);
    }
    newElement = newElement.split('').reversed.join();
  }
  return newElement;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your method to get the average between the two strings?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the code I have running in my project. Hope this helps!

Comment: A copy paste of your code works in my app, so I can say that it works, very well! Now for me to work through it, seems a little advanced (for me at least), will give it some time. Thank you for sharing :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you might follow to achieve such functionality.

##### Approach #1:

You can give your task distant positions instead of continuous position, something like this:

```
Date: 10 April 2019
Name: "some task name"
Index: 10
...
Index: 20
...
Index: 30
```

Here are total 3 tasks with position 10, 20, 30. Now lets say you wanted to move third task in the middle, simply change the position to 15, now you have three task with position 10, 15, 20, I am sure you can sort according to the position when getting all tasks from the database, and I also assume that you can get positions of tasks because user will be re arranging the tasks on a mobile app or web app so you can easily get the positions of surrounding tasks and calculate the middle position of surrounding tasks,
Now lets say you wanted to move the first task(which now have possition index 10) in the middle, simply get the positions of surrounding tasks which is 15 and 20 and calculate the middle which is 17.5 ( (20-15)/2=17.5 ) and here you go, now you have positions 15, 17.5, 20

Someone said there is infinity between 1 and 2 so you are not going to run our of numbers I think, but still of you think you will run out of division soon, you can increase the difference and you can make it 100000...00 instead of 10

##### Approach #2:

You can save all of your tasks in the same document instead of sperate document in stratified json form, something like this:

Tasks: `[ {name:"some name",date: "some date" },{name:"some name",date: "some date"},{name:"some name",date: "some date" }  ]`

By doing this you will get all task at once on the screen and you will parse the json as local array, when user rearrange the task you will simply change the position of that array element locally and save the stratified version of the tasks in database as well, there are some cons of this approach, if you are using pagination it might be difficult to do so but hopefully you will not be using the pagination in task management app and you probably wanted to show all task on the scree at the same time just like Trello does.